# I am trying to use data pulled from one axios get request to make a series of axios get request to the Google Books API

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, axios

I have a database on MongoDB that contains information about books. In react, I am making an axios get request to this database and retrieving an array of 20 objects. I update state with the value of that array. My goal is to map through that array, and using the isbn numbers for each item in the array, make a get request to the Google Books API. I want to match the isbn number from my database to the isbn in the google database to retrieve the cover image for each book. However, when I make the second axios request, sometimes it is successful, but other times I get this error:

createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403 at createError (createError.js:17)at settle (settle.js:19)at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad

I tried using the solution from this post: [My Axios call is returning a 404 error, React/Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772322/my-axios-call-is-returning-a-404-error-react-express)

And I think my questions is similar to this one: 
[Make multiple axios request from response from an axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640466/make-multiple-axios-request-from-response-from-an-axios-request)

```
class Booklist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      googleThumbnail: []
    };
    this.showBooks = this.showBooks.bind(this);
  }

  showBooks() {
    let url = "";
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      url = process.env.DB_URL;
    } else {
      url = "http://localhost:8080/books";
    }

    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      // console.log(res.data);
      let bookData = res.data;
      this.setState({ data: bookData });
      console.log(bookData);
      bookData.map(item => {
        if (item.isbns.length > 0) {
          let url2 = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:${item.isbns[0].isbn13}`;
          return axios.get(url2).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(item => {
          return (
            <Book
              key={item._id}
              title={item.title}
              author={item.author}
              description={item.description}
              // src={this.state.googleThumbnail}
            ></Book>
          );
        })}

        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick={this.showBooks}>
          See All Our Books
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Booklist;
```

Comment: Can you try running only 1 file at a time. Could be the case that google is throttling your requests as you are making 20 requests within no time

Comment: @ShubhamJain Do you know of a way that I could do that? Just call one file at a time or delay the amount of time between each request?

Comment: Not really sure of a way. You can check the API docs if they support bulk request API else you could try with timeout.